# Get value from query string in Python 3 without the [' '] showing up in the value

Tags: python-3.x, http, parsing, query-string, urllib

I have the following code in a **Python 3** http server parse out a URL and then parse out a query string:

```
parsedURL = urlparse(self.path)
parsed = parse_qs(parsedURL.query)
```

say that `parsedURL.query` in this case turns about to be `x=7&=3`.I want to get the 7 and the 3 out and set them equal to variables x and y. I've tried both

```
x = parsed['x']
y = parsed['y']
```

and

```
x = parsed.get('x')
y = parsed.get('y')
```

both of these solutions come up with x = `['7']` and y = `['3']` but I don't want the brackets and single quotes, I want *just* the values `7` and `3`, and I want them to be integers. How do I get the values out and get rid of the brackets/quotes?

Comment: `parse_qsl` might be more suitable for you (`parse_qs` uses this internally, and accumulates the values into lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would simply:

```
x = int(parsed['x'][0])
y = int(parsed['y'][0])
```

or

```
x = int(parsed.get('x')[0])
y = int(parsed.get('y')[0])
```

serve your purpose? You should of course have suitable validation checks, but all you want to do is convert the first element of the returned array to an `int`, so this code will do the business.

This is because the `get()` returns an array of values (I presume!) so if you try parsing `url?x=1&x=2&x=foo` you would get back a list like `['1', '2', 'foo']`. Normally there is only one (or zero, of course) instance of each variable in a query string, so we just grab the first entry with `[0]`.

Note the [documentation for `parse_qs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) says:

> Data are returned as a dictionary. The dictionary keys are the unique query variable names and the values are **lists of values for each name**.

Comment: oh my god that's so simple but it WORKED thank you so much! Can you explain what the part with the `[0]` does? That must be what made it work, since I just remembered I tried doing the `int` thing. If you can't tell, I'm REALLY new to python haha

Comment: OK, added a little more text.

Comment: perfect! I'll set it as the preferred answer but you answered so fast it won't let me quite yet. Thanks again!